# Android Change Location Provider not working

Tags: android, android-location

I've got an App that manages its location manager and location listener in a service.

My location listener is also a new service. 
When some parameters match on a location update or a timer has matched, I change the location provider from gps to passive or from passive to gps.

From passive to gps works fine but from gps to passive does not.

This is my code that changes the providers

```
public void changeGPSProvider(String provider) {
    Log.i("ced", "Change Provider: " + provider);
    if(provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && this.locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5, 1, this.locationListener);         
    } else {
        this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 5, 1, this.locationListener);
    }
}
```

Console prints:

> 02-05 11:05:45.063: I/GCoreUlr(1049): Successfully inserted location
>   02-05 11:05:45.063: I/GCoreUlr(1049): Not calling
>   LocationReportingService, hasMoved: false, elapsed millis: 978046,
>   request: Phone 02-05 11:05:46.865: I/ced(13235): Change Provider:
>   passive

Do you have any idea why? I just see that GPS signal is always working on my device.
Thank you.